# class __dict__ from output **kwargs, *args

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to make a class that will make a dict using `__dict__` out of

```
attrdict(name = ("American","bbbb"),weight=(2,2.5))
```

I trying to start with

```
class attrdict(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        dict.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.__dict__ = self
```

This returns `{'name': ('American', 'bbbb'), 'weight': (2, 2.5)}`, but I need it in a way I can call "American" and it will return 2.

I am stuck. Can someone please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want such result then pass the zipped values:

```
class attrdict(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        dict.__init__(self, dict(*args))
        self.__dict__ = self
```

**Demo:**

```
>>> d = attrdict(zip(("American","bbbb"),(2,2.5)))
>>> d['American']
2
>>> d['bbbb']
2.5
```

Comment: Or, change the line `dict.__init__(self, dict(*args))` to `dict.__init__(self, dict(zip(kwargs['name'], kwargs['weight']))` so the user wouldn't have to do the `zip`.  Of course, this assumes that the passed in elements would have to be `name` and `weight`, in which case these should be explicitly defined in the `__init__` function.